# it expands row when i click on a row but i want to expand row only when i click on a button

Tags: jquery, html

Below code expands a row when i click on row but i want to expand row only when i click on button. I have  a image/button on each row.

**Jquery code**

```
$('.RowToClick').click(function ()
    {
         $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
         {
             if ($(this).is('.RowToClick'))
             {
                 return false;
             }
             $(this).toggle(350);
         });
  });
```

**my html**

```
    <tr class="RowToClick" >
       <td><img src="plus.png"  >
        </td>
    <td><?php echo $id;?>
            </td>
    <td><?php echo $name;?>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="i">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="width:250px;">
        <b>Phone: </b><?php echo $phone;?> <br>
        <b>email: </b><?php echo $email; ?><br>
     <tr>
```

Comment: please share button code and image as you have explain

Comment: The easy way u can add a button/Anchor link an give a class name to that button.then in your jquery code you can replace this - "('.RowToClick').click" with "('.buttonclassName').click" and try.

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor like this

```html
<a href='#' class='your_button_class'>Click to expand</a>
```

**Instead of**

```js
$('.RowToClick').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle(350);
    });
});
```

**Use this**

```js
$('.your_button_class').click(function () {
    $('.RowToClick').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
             $(this).slideToggle(350);
        }
    });
});
```

**So, replace the class on click with your button class or id.**

Comment: Can you be more explicit. What errors do you have. Have you looked in the console?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Replace 'this' from nextAll with '.RowToClick' class and tell me if now is working.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```html
 <button type="submit" class="link">Link</button>
```

**strong text**

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle(350);
    });
});
```